# getting json object from cookie in proper json format in javascript

Tags: javascript, json, object, cookies

**I am storing json object into cookies in browser window, but when I read cookie for the same json object I stored it returns me follwing json object:**

> "j%3A%7B%22request%22%3A%22login%22%2C%22provider%22%3A%22facebook%22%2C%22idd%22%3A1%2C%22auth_token%22%3A%22EAACQG9aNqPcBAFaWZCGG1UGsb1wqxqzaopZAFr1B3ZAR5tnNGQnLGcmuaHFjmvusPcBI9k3k5m6U89K3vZB4ruxadPHZA945lQtpc8fINoKQDQqZBXYhX0j0ZCupdxWc2VP5b86MvWtTGzBvWSxgEqHM74ZBcEhWZBF5PKc41VwOWAgZDZD%22%2C%22auth_name%22%3A%22Tushar%20Bochare%22%2C%22auth_email%22%3A%22mytusshar%40gmail.com%22%2C%22auth_id%22%3A%221414815471964057%22%2C%22cognito_id%22%3A%22us-east-1%3A2eb23ae9-bb78-40f7-b614-efe145dc1b7b%22%2C%22accessKey%22%3A%22ASIAJSIGNL2VUL3WVVZQ%22%2C%22secretKey%22%3A%22kKrFQzIl%2F4%2BqNTRa2XN4HMHjvzdaZo988QKf%2FLjO%22%2C%22status%22%3A1%2C%22name%22%3A%22fb%20tush%22%2C%22city%22%3A%22Akola%22%2C%22email%22%3A%22mytusshar%40gmail.com%22%2C%22message%22%3A%22LOGIN%20SUCCESS%22%7D"

**my original JSON object that I stored is:**

> {"request":"login","provider":"facebook","idd":1,"auth_token":"yuiyuiiiyiyiiyissflkjljwqxqzaopZAFr1B3ZAR5tnNGQnLGcmuaHFjmvusPcBI9k3k5m6U89K3vZB4ruxadPHZA945lQtpc8fINoKQDQqZBXYhX0j0ZCupdxWc2VP5b86MvWtTGzBvWSxgEqHM74ZBcEhWZBF5PKc41VwOWAgZDZD","auth_name":"xyz smith","auth_email":"xyz@gmail.com","auth_id":"3123213171964057","cognito_id":"us-east-2:21wd2fh5-bb78-40a6-b614-efe145df2c4c","accessKey":"ASIAQFXSYL2VUL3WVVZQ","secretKey":"kKrKJzIl/4+qNTRa2YS4JBYjvzdaZo100QKf/LjO","status":1,"name":"fb xyz","city":"starcity","email":"xyz@gmail.com"}

**It is replcaing all special characters like single quotes, braces, colon, quomma with its ascii code.
Is there any function in JS to directly retrieve json object from cookies?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `decodeURI(str)`to decode your string. This function replace every **%x** characters.

Find [doc here](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_decodeuri.asp)

Answer (score 1):

> You can use JSON.stringify() when storing  "json object" & you can use
>   JSON.parse() to read json object from cookie.

Comment: I have tried doing that but it's not working, it is showing error: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token % in JSON at position 0
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)`